# When is a match counted as won, even if i was AFK for part of it?

Tags: league-of-legends

Sometimes, if you leave a match and your team wins 4v5 you'll get the match counted as leave instead of win.

I remember reading somewhere that for the match to be counted as a win you need either to be connected in the moment the game finishes (even if you've been AFK earlier in the game) or you need to have been active for some % of the length of the game.

Is this correct? What are exactly the criteria that decide whether a match in which a player has been AFK will be counted as leave or with a normal win/loss result for that player?

Comment: Typically these things are not publicly well defined to prevent people from taking advantage of them. Please do not take advantage of any answers you receive or go AFK intentionally for any reason. I realize that connection issues can happen, but if you habitually have connection issues, try not to play ranked.

Answer (score 1):

This is all handled by the Leaver Buster. The match will automatically count as a leave (or loss in ranked) **if the player doesn't do anything for 5 minutes**. Note that this only counts if the player **is AFK at the end of the game**.

This basically means: If you are AFK earier in the game and your reconnect (even in the last 3 seconds) it will **not** count as a loss. However if you aren't performing any actions for 5 minutes and you remain AFK you will get the leaving penalty.

Comment: Are the minutes counted cumulatively? How will a match in which I'm afk 6 minutes in the middle of the game then come back and leave again 10 seconds before the end be counted? What about a match in which I'm afk 3 minutes in the middle and 3 minutes before the end?

Comment: I don't think it is cumulatively.

Comment: This is inaccurate. I reconnected for a game, after being AFK for ~15 minutes (internet issues), came back, won with a single push, and still got leave.

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple:

If you are connected at the end of the game it is a win.

If you are disconnected or have been afk for more than 5 minutes in a row at the end of the game it is a loss.

i.e. if the game ends at minute 30 and you haven't acted since minute 25 you get a loss.

You could disconnect for 40 minutes and connect 5 seconds from the end and get the win.

You could connect for 40 minutes and disconnect 5 seconds from the end and get the leave. (I've actually had that happen, LoL crashed as we were seiging the second nexus tower, by the time I reconnected the game was over and I had a loss on my record).

Comment: This is inaccurate. I reconnected for a game, after being AFK for ~15 minutes (internet issues), came back, won with a single push, and still got leave.